# What are the steps to get to a perspective projection matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

[image]

I have been reading about it for quite a while, but I still could not understand very well the steps it takes to compose a perspective projection matrix. Can anyone explain all the matrices and their respective jobs in composing a final perspective projection matrix?

Comment: Perspective projections are non-linear, so they can't be represented by matrices... unless you add an extra dimension for "projective space" or something.

Comment: @mr_e_man Yeah, i mean like a 4d matrix.

Comment: Did you search the site for related questions? You might find your answer already elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that formula in the picture you provided, but here are my thoughts.

---

A perspective projection onto a horizontal plane $\{z = a\}$, with focus $(0,0,0)$ and focal length $a$, maps a point $(x,y,z)$ to
$$P(x,y,z) = \left(\frac{ax}{z}, \frac{ay}{z}, a\right) = \frac az(x,y,z)$$
Verify that any point on the plane $(x,y,a)$ maps to itself.

---

In projective space, two points (excluding the origin itself) are equivalent if they're on the same line through the origin; for any number $k \neq 0$,
$$(x,y,z,w) \sim (kx,ky,kz,kw)$$

So the projection becomes, for any point on the space $\{w = 1\}$,
$$P(x,y,z,1) = \left(\frac{ax}{z}, \frac{ay}{z}, a, 1\right) = \frac az\left(x,y,z,\frac za\right) \sim \left(x,y,z,\frac za\right)$$
converting to matrix notation,
$$= \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ z/a \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1/a&0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
(Notice, it doesn't matter whether $w$ is $1$ or anything else, because of the column of zeroes. I don't know if that's important here.)

So, for a projection through the point $(0,0,0,1)$ onto a horizontal plane $\{(x,y,a,1)\}$, the matrix is

$$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1/a&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

---

Now, to make a projection with any focus and any plane orientation, we only need to apply translations and rotations to what we already have. If the focus is $\vec c$ (and the focal length and orientation are the same as before), then the projection of $\vec x$ is $P(\vec x - \vec c) + \vec c$.

Similarly, if the plane's orientation is different, so that the normal vector is $R(0,0,1)$ for some rotation matrix $R$ (and the focus is $(0,0,0)$), then the projection is $RP(R^{-1}\vec x)$.

If the focus and orientation are both different, then the above formulas are combined into $RP(R^{-1}(\vec x - \vec c)) + \vec c$.

But this is a 3D formula. In 4D, the translation can be represented by a matrix

$$T = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&c_x \\ 0&1&0&c_y \\ 0&0&1&c_z \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

and the rotation matrix gets extra $0$'s and a $1$ in the corner. Now the projection is

$$P'(\vec x) = TRPR^{-1}T^{-1}\vec x$$
$$P' = TRPR^{-1}T^{-1}$$